# sqlite capacitor ionic inspect database-data with database-console in platform===web mode

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, webassembly, capacitor

I am using the capacitor-community/sqlite plugin. Is there any way I can inspect data in the database when I am starting my app in the web mode, i.e. viewing the app in the browser?

I am using this sql-wasm.wasm file for the web database I think.

my app is based on this project, but data-access is even more primitive right now:
https://github.com/jepiqueau/ionic-angular-sqlite-starter

here are the docs:
https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite/blob/master/docs/Web-Usage.md
(from here: https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite#documentation--apis)

I'd like similar functionality as with the H2-Console for example.

this is what the database looks like right now when inspecting with chrome, so pretty useless bytes:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite/discussions/334#discussion-4473905

i.e. you can't inspect the database with a tool equivalent to the H2-Console.

BUT there is an alternative solution:
you can create your own database-console-page inside your app to view the data